# I disagree and think this answer is a Comment

Tags: discussion

I am referring to the question [how-to-add-a-confirm-dialog-to-a-command-button](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/2046/how-to-add-a-confirm-dialog-to-a-command-button)

The 'answer' by @techtrekker appears to me to be nothing more than a +1 I agree with the answer already provided.

@metadaddy could you explain further why you think it was a valid answer?

Answer (score 2):

Happy to explain my reasoning... These questions are often a judgement call; in this case, I thought the additional information about incompatibility of a JS prompt and action method on the same button and the advice to proxy via action function or JS remoting tipped the balance towards it being acceptable as an answer. I do tend towards 'let it be' unless it's clear that there is a problem. If there are multiple 'this is not an answer' flags, then I'm happy to move it to being a comment.

Comment: Thanks Pat, couldn't agree more about it being a judgement call.I see you've deleted the comments, that was wise. This is probably the best example yet I've seen of something right on the knifes edge